# Issue with Azeroth Core Docker install on Windows 10: Pro

Tags: docker, azerothcore

https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/install-with-docker

On step 4 of the guide I am getting "Service ac-worldserver is not available".

[image: Docker Desktop Screenshot]

[image: Gitbash Console]

I am unsure how to troubleshoot as I am new to docker.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to move on and open a seperate terminal. Then run the following command using the worldserver name from docker desktop.

winpty docker attach azerothcore-wotlk-ac-worldserver-1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).